# SQL command - Getting all column entry from a not so unique ID

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

[image: Table to pull data from]

I'm trying to list all data in the Color column field as the following:

- Y, M, C, K, O, crystal barrier flood, hr matte uv flood

but I'm having trouble because the UniqueProdID are all the same.

This is what my query looks like

```
SELECT Unit, Color
FROM ProductColor
WHERE UniqueProdID = ‘50060’
ORDER BY Unit;
```

and my current result is 1Y

Thank you in advance:-)

Comment: What you are saying here makes no sense. The result doesn't match the query nor the data sample.

Comment: What? Given that sample data and your SQL you could never ever get `1|K` as a result. `1|K` isn't a record in your sample. Your SQL would show every single record here and if it isn't, this either isn't the SQL you are actually using, or this sample data isn't actually in that table, or you've got some white space around your `UniqueProdID` like spaces that is suppressing results.

Comment: could you elaborate your result please?

Comment: sorry, my current result is 1Y.

Comment: You are just getting one record?

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and **expected results.** [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: Yes, only 1 record. It's really weird... even when I use Select *

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would be giving each ID a unique ID instead of the same number, it does not meet the standards of a primary key which is what an ID is supposed to be (unique) if anything you could add something like a batch ID in a seperate column eg have an id specific to bright colors or an id specific to dark colors etc. If you want all the colors returned then this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductColor
```

will return everything in the table, but I am assuming this will not work until you have assigned individual primary keys.

```
productID   unit   batchID        color
50060       1      brightcolor    Y
50061       2      brightcolor    M
50062       3      darkcolor      C
50063       4      darkcolor      K

SELECT Unit, Color
FROM ProductColor
WHERE batchID = 'brightcolor'
ORDER BY unit;
```

would return all colors with the brightcolor batchID. if you want it displayed as 1|K then you would need to concatanate the fields after you have returned your results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a concatenation with commas?

```
SELECT
    LEFT
        (
            (
                SELECT Color + ', '
                FROM ProductColor
                WHERE UniqueProdID = '50060'
                ORDER BY Unit
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            )
        ,
            LEN
                (
                    (
                        SELECT Color + ', '
                        FROM ProductColor
                        WHERE UniqueProdID = '50060'
                        ORDER BY Unit
                        FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
                ) - 1
        )
```

Comment: Thank you but I get no result when using your code. I do want commas to help me separate out all the data. Sorry, total noob here:-(

Comment: It returns NULL?

Comment: I'm using an ESKO product and the result is as follows <<TNameConfigExample/>> which is basically null. I'm able to pull other data with no problem, just this particular one, with the UniqueProdID not being so unique.

Comment: I have assumed you are using SQL Server. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm using OBDC to connect to the sql database and the software is LabelTraxx.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Chris.